# How do you sideload apk files in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, android, windows-11

<sup>*(Windows 11 was only released to developers two weeks ago, so answers to this question could change if you're reading this after July, 2021)*</sup>

Windows 11 can run Android apps so I decided to upgrade to Windows 11 to test my game, however how can I sideload a `.apk` on Windows 11?

- I have a `.apk` for an Android game I'm working on [both arm & x86 support] and when I download the file on my phone, I can sideload the `.apk` easily once I enable sideloaded apps
- When I load the same `.apk` on Windows 11, it says `How do you want to open this file?` and lets me select programs from a list, which is the way Windows behaves for any file extension Windows doesn't recognize

I haven't tested the `.apk` on an x86 Android or Chrome OS device, but the unzipped `.apk` does contain directory `lib/x86_64` with the Godot library and Windows should give a different error if the `.apk` was malformed.

Answer (score 5):

At this time, as of 11 of July 2021, the only thing we are sure of is that
downloaded APKs will work, but the mechanism is yet unknown.

Microsoft Distinguished Engineer Miguel de Icaza addressed those concerns on Twitter. Icaza simply
[responded](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/1408222245265330178)
“Yes” to one Twitter user who asked if Windows 11 would run APKs obtained from outside the Amazon Appstore. Then, in response to another user who called the Amazon Appstore “the Diet Coke of App Stores,” he
[said](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/1408195921041629187)
“then bring your own APK”.

From this we understand that Microsoft’s partnership with Amazon
wouldn’t restrict Windows 11 to specific Android apps.

It's also unknown how well these APKs will function.
Apps like the Google Play Store or Google Maps won’t run without
Play Services, which are not included in Windows 11.

[xda-developers points out](https://www.xda-developers.com/windows-11-support-installing-android-apps-amazon-appstore)
that certain third-party apps may be missing some functionality,
one example would be the Twitter app that could perhaps be installed,
but you won’t receive push notifications.

Comment: After we can actually install APK's we should have a more permanent answer, though this is the best answer right now.

Comment: Does NOT WORK!!

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников: Microsoft is running late with the project, but there's still hope for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using instructions from https://www.notebookcheck.net/Tutorial-Get-started-with-the-Android-Subsystem-on-Windows-11-Sideload-APKs-and-even-enable-Google-Play-Services.574829.0.html and some other sites, I have been able to sideload an Android .apk file on Windows 11.

First, I had to setup my machine so that it was compatible with the Amazon Store (so that the Microsoft Store would let me install the Amazon AppStore).

1. In my BIOS, I enabled virtualization (your instructions will vary).
2. I made sure I was still setup for the Windows Insider Program (Beta Channel) under "Windows Update Settings".
3. I ran the "Windows Features" app (a.k.a. Turn Windows Features on or off"), and enabled "Virtual Machine Platform").
4. I installed all the Windows 11 Updates, using "Check for updates" repeatedly, and rebooted my machine.
5. I ran the Windows Store, and searched for "Amazon AppStore" and installed it.  If you can't find the "Amazon AppStore", recheck all of the above steps, or try rebooting, or just wait an hour or so.  It showed up eventually for me.  Next, I ran the Amazon AppStore to confirm that WSA (see below) is working and that sideloading should work.

Supposedly, all the above steps will be done for us in the future, but for now, you need to do these steps, and also check that your machine is compatible (e.g. supported processor, supports Virtualization, etc.)

Next, I followed the instructions from the above-mentioned article:

1. Download and unzip [Android SDK Platform Tools for Windows](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
2. Run "Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA)", and enable "Developer Mode" in that app.  Leave the WSA app running.
3. From a cmd prompt, type "adb connect localhost:58526".  The adb command came with the "Android SDK Platform Tools" you installed in step 6.  In my case, I got an "authentication" error, but it still worked.  If that doesn't work for you, you might also try replacing "localhost" with your machine's local IP address.
4. Run the command "adb install yourapp.apk" where "yourapp.apk" is the Android package you want to install.
5. After installation completes, go to the Windows Start Menu, type in the name of your app, and run it.
6. When I tried to uninstall the app using "adb uninstall", I got an error message.  To uninstall the app, I had to go to "Add or Remove Programs".